# Localization alternative to Resx file

Tags: c#, localization, resx

**Why I don't want to use Resx files:**

I am looking for an alternative for resx files to offer multilanguage support for my project, due to the following reasons:

- I don't like to specify a "messageId" when writing messages, it is more effort and it is annoying for the flow as I don't see what the log message would actually say and I would need to open another tab to edit the message
- Sometimes I use code inline because I don't want to create new variables for to easy steps (e. g. `Log.Info("Iterated {i+1} times");`). Using variables or doing simple calculations inline makes the whole code sometimes more clearly than creating additional code lines

**What I could imagine instead:**

An external application which crawls a compiled exe for all strings, giving you the opportunity to ignore/add strings which should be translated. It could create a XML or Json file for all languages as well then. It would replace all strings with a hash/id so that a lookup for strings in all languages is still possible.

**Am I the only one who is not happy with the commonly used Resx / centralized string db solution? Do I miss points why this wouldn't be a good idea?**

Comment: You're describing gettext here. And there [seems to be C# support, too](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/C_0023.html). The resources approach works for more things than just strings, though.

Comment: Hm to be exactly you need to edit the code inside of your project and what I am suggesting doesn't require any changes in my project code

Comment: There is no magic. If you don't want to use what Microsoft built-in approach, you have to edit the code to use another.

Comment: @LexLi the suggested approach doesn't require any code changes, please read/reasses it again

Comment: @kentor to put your imagination into practice, where does that code come from?

Answer (score 2):

One reason for relying on established approaches instead of implementing your own format is translation. It really depends on how your resources are translated: if it is done by volunteers with a technical background who don't mind working in a plain text editor, then you are free to come up with your own resource format. If on the other hand you send out your resources to professional translators who are not very technical and who prefer to work in a translation environment with integrated terminology management, translation memory, spelling and quality checks etc. it is quite likely that this environment will not be able to handle your homemade resource format.

Since I already mentioned professional translation environments: some of these tools rely on IDs to figure out which strings are old and which are new. If you use the approach that the text is the ID every fixed typo in your source language means that you create a new string that needs to be translated - and paid for. If the translator sees that the source text for a string has changed he can have a look at the change, notice that a typo has been fixed, decide that the translation is still OK and sign the string off, without extra translation cost.

By the way, if you want good localizations for strings like `Log.Info("Iterated {i+1} times");` you have to find some way of dealing with plural forms correctly. Some languages have different grammatical rules for different numbers (see the [Unicode Language Plural Rules](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) for an overview). Just because something is easy to do in code does not mean that it is easy to localize, I'm afraid.

To sum this up: if you want to create your own resource format, talk with your translators. Ask them which formats they can handle. Think about translation related limitations that come with your format, for example if there are any characters that the translators should not use because they break your strings? Apostrophes and quotes are prime candidates here because they are often used as string delimiters in resource files, or < and & if you decide to go the XML way. Think about a conversion to [XLIFF](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/xliff-core/xliff-core.html) and back: most translation environments can handle XLIFF.